# Yii Authorization Assignment - Where does Yii get the Id?

Tags: authentication, yii, rbac, role-based-access-control

I'm trying to implement my first RBAC system:

I'm getting to this part:

In oficial documentation, they have an example with a username:

```
$auth->assign('adminRole', 'userA'); 
$auth->assign('adminRole', 'userB');
```

However, I did found that, on my case, the ID will work instead.

```
$auth->assign('adminRole', '8'); 
$auth->assign('adminRole', '9');
```

**Why did the ID work, and not the username?** I presumed it was because, somewhere, we have overwrite the `getId()` method from `UserIdentity`.

However, after keep following the documentation, and the *Yii* code, I notice that the `assign()` method, does not accept a child of `CUserIdentity`, it uses, `IWebUser` interface, instead.

I then go to `CWebUser` and I notice the `getId()` method has the following:

```
/**
     * Returns a value that uniquely represents the user.
     * @return mixed the unique identifier for the user. If null, it means the user is a guest.
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getState('__id');
    }
```

I keep following this, and I end up on a `$_SESSION[$key]` and now I'm confused.

What id is that? I presume is the primary key of my user database table.

But how does CWebUser knows about my user database table (that's called `tbl_site_user`) btw.

The only configuration I have that do relates the user, and the authorization is this, on my main config file:

```
'authManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID'=>'db',
        ),
```

Where did Yii got the ID on `$auth->assign` *second argument*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in your code you call [CWebUser::login()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail), probably with `Yii::app()->user->login($identity);`.

```
public function login($identity,$duration=0)
{
    $id=$identity->getId();
    $states=$identity->getPersistentStates();
    if($this->beforeLogin($id,$states,false))
    {
        $this->changeIdentity($id,$identity->getName(),$states);
...
```

This method accepts your CUserIdentity object, extracts the id from it, and calls [CWebUser::changeIdentity()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#changeIdentity-detail).

```
protected function changeIdentity($id,$name,$states)
{
    Yii::app()->getSession()->regenerateID(true);
    $this->setId($id);
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->loadIdentityStates($states);
}
```

Where [CWebUser::setId()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setId-detail) is called.

```
public function setId($value)
{
    $this->setState('__id',$value);
}
```

Which sets the `__id` session state.

Comment: I'm looking at the default Yii setup. No modules, nothing. I have a action login on my site controller. Is the only login I have. It doesn't accept any CUserIdentity. I have, however, a method authenticate under `LoginForm` MODEL. But there's no call for a changeIdentity. So, unfortunately, I can't really follow your steps. :(

Comment: You just need to find `CWebUser::login()`, as that calls `CWebUser::changeIdentity` and all subsequent steps. `Yii::app->user` is a `CWebUser` object (by default). Unless you've made major changes to the default code, `Yii::app()->user->login()` should appear somewhere in the LoginForm class.

Comment: Find it. ;) All clear. Thanks a lot for taking the time to deep into it.